# How to save a word template for a content type without filling in required fields

Tags: sharepoint, moss, content-type, word-template

I have a content type that has required fields.  I have associated Word document with the content type as a template.  I now want to edit the Word template, but word won't allow me to save the template without filling in the required fields.  However, if I fill in the required fields and save the document, then those fields get populated with my values when you create a new document.  This isn't good because I want the fields to be blank when a new document is created - I want the users to be forced to fill in those values.

I can update the templace by updating the colums and making them optional, editing the word template, saving the template & then changing the columns back to required.  This is a PITA - there's got to be a better way, does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this work around:  When I edit the template (ie go to the content type settings --> Advanced settings --> Edit Template), I make my changes and save the file locally.  Then, on the same page that I clicked the "Edit Template" link, I upload the copy that I saved locally.  Saving it locally avoids the validation that happens when you try to save it back to SharePoint. But the validation still gets applied to any new documents of that content type.  So no need to toggle the settings off & on!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the document as a normal document content type, making the changes, saving it, then moving back over the top of where the old version of the template was?

Comment: Hmmm...  Food for thought - I'll have to give that a try.  I'll try creating a content type with the same columns, but not required, that way I won't have to keep futsing with required/optional columns.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found is to modify document templates on library level. Just upload a new document template for the required content type.
However, this will not work if you'd like to re-use one and same content type across different document libraries.